# Copy/paste filtered tables from spreadsheet into email

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

I have working VBA code that sends an email to each recipient on my spreadsheet and includes in the body of the text information from the spreadsheet.

The workbook contains a couple tables to copy/paste into each email.
The data from each table needs to be filtered to the data that applies to each recipient.

For example:
The email is being sent to a Regional leader and includes scores for their Region overall.
I have 1 table that includes manager scores which can be filtered by Region.
On a second tab, I have a table for each Region that drills down the scores by type of service.

So for the SouthWest Regional leader, I would like to filter table 1 to only show managers in the SouthWest Region, copy/paste that table directly into the email and then go to the Service Type tables and copy the SouthWest table and paste into the email.

Finally I would like to copy the employee level details which reside on a separate tab, to a workbook and attach it to the email. This too would need to be specific to employees within each region.

Below is the email code.
I also have code that filters the data based on the region.

```vb
Sub SendMailtoRFE()

Dim outapp As New Outlook.Application
Dim outmail As Outlook.Mailitem
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim sFile1 As String
Dim TempFilePath As String

Environ ("UserProfile")

Set outapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")

sFile1 = "Infographic"
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "Roadside Assistance " 'FIND OUT HOW TO CLEAN UP THE NAME: "Temp" added to file name

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sFile1).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=TempFilePath & sFile1 & ".pdf"

On Error Resume Next

For i = 3 To wks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With outmail
        .To = wks.Range("C" & i).Value
        .Subject = wks.Range("A" & i).Value & " Region Roadside Assistance YTD Communication"
        .HTMLBody = "Dear " & wks.Range("C" & i).Value & "," & "<br></br>" & _
          "You've shared how important Roadside Assistance is for your personal auto clients. As one of the highest frequency types of losses, success or failure " & _
          "here may be seen as a signal of the overall value of the program." & "<br></br><br></br>" & _
          "Here are the results for clients in your area who completed a survey. Year to date, the NPS was " & FormatPercent(wks.Range("K" & i).Value, 0) & _
          " based on " & wks.Range("H" & i).Value & " total responses." & _
          " The overall score for all regions is " & FormatPercent(wks.Range("K12").Value, 0) & "." & "<br></br><br></br>" & _
          "Below are a few additional details to help you understand your region's score. " & _
          "Please follow up with any questions or concerns." & "<br></br><br></br>" & vbNewLine & _
          "**Please note, the table containing MLGA scores shows only the MLGA's where 5 or more survey responses were received.**"
        
        .Attachments.Add (TempFilePath & sFile1 & ".pdf")
        .display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set outmail = Nothing
Next i

Set outapp = Nothing

End Sub

''Filter Region on the MLGA Tow NPS Score Tab
Sub FilterSouthWest()
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("MLGA TOW NPS Score")

With wks.Range("A2:C2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="9A"
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

This is the Tables tab and how it is currently laid out:
[image: This is the Tables tab and how it is currently laid out]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to set the range on the filtered table and copy/paste them into the email using  `WordEditor`. To insert the html text create a temporary file and use `.InsertFile`, This converts the html formatting into word formatting. You may need to add a wait between the copy/paste action depending on the amount of data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub SendMailtoRFE()

    'sheet names
    Const PDF = "Infographic" ' attachment
    Const WS_S = "MLGA TOW NPS Score" ' filtered score data
    Const WS_R = "Regions" ' names and emails
    Const WS_T = "Tables" ' Regions Tables

    Dim ws As Worksheet, sPath As String, sPDFname As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    ' region code for filter
    Dim dictRegions As Object, region
    Set dictRegions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dictRegions
        .Add "NorthEast", "6A"
        .Add "NorthWest", "7A"
        .Add "SouthEast", "8A"
        .Add "SouthWest", "9A"
    End With
    
    sPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    sPDFname = sPath & "Roadside Assistance " & PDF & ".pdf"
    Sheets(PDF).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sPDFname

    Dim outapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outmail As Outlook.Mailitem
    Dim outInsp As Object, oWordDoc
    
    Dim wsRegion As Worksheet
    Dim sRegion As String, sEmailAddr As String, rngScore As Range
    Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range, tmpHTML As String
    
    ' scores
    With Sheets(WS_S)
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngScore = .Range("A2:G" & lastrow) ' 5 columns
    End With
    
    ' open outlook
    Set outapp = New Outlook.Application
    
    ' regions
    Set wsRegion = Sheets(WS_R)
    lastrow = wsRegion.Cells(wsRegion.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 3 To lastrow '
    
        sRegion = wsRegion.Range("A" & i).Value
        sEmailAddr = wsRegion.Range("C" & i).Value
        tmpHTML = HTMLFile(wsRegion, i)
        
        ' region
        With rngScore
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=dictRegions(sRegion) ' filter col C
            Set Table1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        
        ' Service Type Table
        Set Table2 = Sheets(WS_T).ListObjects(sRegion).Range ' Table named same as region
        'Debug.Print dictRegions(sRegion), sRegion, Table1.Address, Table2.Address
    
        Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        n = n + 1
        With outmail
            .To = sEmailAddr
            .Subject = sRegion & " Region Roadside Assistance YTD Communication"
            .Attachments.Add sPDFname
            .display
        End With
        
        Set outInsp = outmail.GetInspector
        Set oWordDoc = outInsp.WordEditor
        'Wait 1
        With oWordDoc
           .Content.Delete
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.InsertFile tmpHTML, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
           Table1.Copy
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = vbCrLf ' blank line
           'Wait 1
           Table2.Copy
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste
           'Wait 1
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Set oWordDoc = Nothing
        Set outInsp = Nothing
        Set outmail = Nothing
        
        ' delete temp html file
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill tmpHTML
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Wait 1
    Next
    ' end
    Sheets(WS_S).AutoFilterMode = False
    Set outapp = Nothing
    AppActivate Application.Caption ' back to excel
    MsgBox n & " Emails created", vbInformation
End Sub

Function HTMLFile(ws As Worksheet, i As Long) As String

    Const CSS = "p{font:14px Verdana};h1{font:14px Verdana Bold};"
   
    ' template
    Dim s As String
    s = "<html><style>" & CSS & "</style><h1>Dear #NAME#,</h1>" & _
    "<p>You've shared how important Roadside Assistance is for your personal auto clients.<br/>" & vbLf & _
    "As one of the highest frequency types of losses, success or failure " & vbLf & _
    "here may be seen as a signal of the overall value of the program.</p>" & vbLf & _
    "<p>Here are the results for clients in your area who completed a survey.</p> " & vbLf & _
    "<li>Year to date, the NPS was <b>#NPS_YTD#</b> " & vbLf & _
    "based on <b>#RESPONSES#</b> total responses.</li> " & vbLf & _
    "<li>The overall score for all regions is <b>#NPS_ALL#</b>,</li>" & vbLf & _
    "<p>Below are a few additional details to help you understand your region's score. " & vbLf & _
    "Please follow up with any questions or concerns." & "</p>" & vbNewLine & vbLf & _
    "<p><i>**Please note, the table containing MLGA scores shows only the MLGA's where 5 " & vbLf & _
    "or more survey responses were received.**</i></p></html>"

    s = Replace(s, "#NAME#", ws.Cells(i, "C"))
    s = Replace(s, "#NPS_YTD#", FormatPercent(ws.Cells(i, "K"), 0))
    s = Replace(s, "#RESPONSES#", ws.Cells(i, "H"))
    s = Replace(s, "#NPS_ALL#", FormatPercent(ws.Cells(12, "K"), 0))

    Dim ff: ff = FreeFile
    HTMLFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now(), "~yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".htm"
    Open HTMLFile For Output As #ff
    Print #ff, s
    Close #ff
       
End Function

Sub Wait(n As Long)
    Dim t As Date
    t = DateAdd("s", n, Now())
    Do While Now() < t
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: CPD1802 - This is seriously awesome! The Email looks a million times better than what I was putting together! Thank you for taking the time to completely re-write my code here. Everything worked great for the first person/region but the code stopped and I got a Script out of range error when it tried to move on to the next person. This is the place it stopped:
  ' Service Type Table
        Set Table2 = Sheets(WS_T).ListObjects(sRegion).Range ' Table named same as region
        'Debug.Print dictRegions(sRegion), sRegion, Table1.Address, Table2.Address

Comment: @JBeets I assumed (maybe wrongly!!) that every region had a table named the same as the region.

Comment: I added a picture to the original post that shows the table lay out. Each tab on that tab is named based on the region; ie - Southwest, Northeast, etc.

Comment: @JBeets Are all the region tables on the same sheet ? What is the value in column A for the second person ? Is there a table with that value ? Check exact spelling, no leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Yes, all on the same sheet. Column A is the service code "Tow, Batter Jump, Etc". I can make it whatever it needs to be. I was trying to figure it out but your code is too smart for me :)

Comment: @JBeets I meant on the sheet where the email address are. This value in your code `.Subject = wks.Range("A" & i).Value`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. There was the problem. I had the table naming convention different than what I had labeled in Column A with the email address. Thank you for your patience and this awesome code!

Comment: Some of the information is not copying over correctly. I thought I might need to add the Wait and that seemed to help some but even adding in all of the waits It copy/pastes the table but there is no data in the table. Its like it is filtered to blanks. The Regions tab lists in Column A and B 
SouthWest 9A - correct
Rocky_Mtn 9V - Incorrect
Great_Atlantic 9P - Incorrect
NorthWest 9N - correct
Great_Lakes 9K - Incorrect
South_Central 9H - Incorrect
Great_Plains 9F - Incorrect
SouthEast 9C - Correct
NorthEast 9B - Correct

Comment: @Jbeets Try adding a wait between the copy and the paste. You can increase the time to 2 seconds ie `wait 2`

Comment: With oWordDoc
           .Content.Delete
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.InsertFile tmpHTML, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
           Table1.Copy
        Wait 2
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Paste
           .Paragraphs.Add.Range.Text = vbCrLf ' blank line     Is that where you meant? If so, it didnt work. Still pasting a blank table.

Comment: @JBeets Is is table1 and table2  or always table2

Comment: It is always the first table that is copied into the email from WS_S. (WS_S = "MLGA TOW NPS Score" ' filtered score data)

Comment: @JBeets Have you configured `dictRegions` for all the regions with their code ?

Comment: Lord have mercy! Ok, that darn naming convention again. I promise, I am done bothering you now. Thank you again for your patience and your time. So appreciated!